# Auto number for big data

Tags: database-design, auto-increment

I'm working with application that can have millions of data. Just wondering if it is ok to use auto_number as primary key. I have read that bigint, int etc has limit. So for example site is on live for 10 years. Is it ok to use auto_number in it. Does big websites like facebook also use auto_number as their primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a 64 bit system, an INT(eger), [2^64  =   18,446,744,073,709,551,616](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two), so if you have an insert every nanosecond, your system will run out of numbers after approximately [600 years](http://web2.0calc.com/) - I wouldn't worry too much! :-)